# Why don't GUI sub-account receive addresses match ledger device receive addresses?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, address, ledger, sub-address, account

I'm new to Monero so probably just a misconception on my part, but the GUi primary receive address for primary account matches the nano X XMR/0 main address, where as the sub-account primary receive address (created in the Gui) doesn't match the nano X XMR/1 main address.  I would have thought that the accounts on the nano X correspond to the accounts in the Gui, but that does not appear to be the case.

Can someone explain how to properly use the accounts in the ledger vs Gui?

Comment: Seriously? It's been almost a year and not one person has even acknowledged this question? I'm so over Monero.

Comment: [Monero (XMR) - Ledger Support](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006352934-Monero-XMR-?support=true) wrt your question and [Code of Conduct](https://monero.stackexchange.com/conduct) wrt your comment.